# ViewComponents from another project not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm using ASP.Net Core 5.0 for a web application in which I'm using ViewComponents. The ViewComponent classes are defined in **another project**. **The main project** has too many views so I added:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>
  <RazorCompileOnPublish>true</RazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

in the .csproj file, reducing the compile time from 120 seconds to 10. But then I faced a problem. The ViewComponents are not detected anymore in my main project. They don't appear in view results and even not suggested by intellisense.
The ViewComponent:

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "EntityForm")]
public class EntityFormViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        if (ViewData.ContainsKey("ViewMode") && ((ViewMode)ViewData["ViewMode"] == ViewMode.Create || (ViewMode)ViewData["ViewMode"] == ViewMode.Edit || (ViewMode)ViewData["ViewMode"] == ViewMode.Delete))
            return View("EntityForm");
        else
            return View("EntityGrid");
    }
}
```

The project hierarchy:
[image]

None of the ViewComponents shown in the image work with `RazorCompileOnBuild` set to `false`.
ViewComponent usage:

```
<vc:entity-form />
```

Comment: Could you please share the snippet for your `ViewComponent` and screenshot of your directory where your `Component` is located.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Done. But please consider, without `<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>` the code works fine so I don't have any design or implementation problem.

Comment: Please include the hierarchy of `EntityFormViewComponent` folder as well. In addition how are you calling this on your `layout` page.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Dear Farid, please note that the project works just fine with `RazorCompileOnBuild` set to true. So we're sure the problem is not about the design and usage of ViewComponents, it seems the problem is about project dependency management and compilation of the views. Although I include the info you requested. And I'm not using the ViewComponent in my `layout` page, but I'm using it all across the project. I've added an example of the usage too. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details, Yes I am also thinking that your components are designed accordingly.